# How does one assign column names to tables in dataset?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have this code

```
 SqlConnection conn = Database.GetConnection();
        //not sure why doing this bit (bit between this comment and next
        //SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From CarType", conn);
        DataSet DataSetRentals2 = new DataSet("CustomerSQLTable");

        DataTable table = new DataTable("CustomerSQLTable"); //you can name it
        DataTable table2 = new DataTable("CarRental");
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer", conn);
            conn.Open();
           ///this might brake the code
           /// 
           adapter.Fill(DataSetRentals2,"CustomerSQLTable");
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM CarRental", conn);
            adapter.Fill(DataSetRentals2, "CarRental");
                            adapter.Fill(DataSetRentals2, "CarRental");
        }

        CustomerGrid.DataSource = DataSetRentals2;
        CustomerGrid.DataMember = "CustomerSQLTable";
```

CarRGrid.DataSource = DataSetRentals2.Tables["CarRental"];
            CarRGrid.DataMember = "CarRental";

the teacher gave me this code to link them in a relationship so that when i click on one customer number in one data grid and for it to only return corresponding records in the other.

```
DataRowView selectedRow =
                (DataRowView)CustomerGrid.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
            DataSetRentals2.Tables["CarRental"].DefaultView.RowFilter =
                "CustomerNo = " + selectedRow.Row["CustomerNo"].ToString();.
```

so what i think i need to do is to name the columns in the dataset. But i have no idea how to do this. I'm sure there must be a way an I'm sure you guy's can easily tell me it. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why don't you use `SELECT column1, column2, column3...` instead of `SELECT *` so they're defined when you retrieve them

Answer (score 1):

```
dataTable.Columns[0].ColumnName = "MyColumnName";
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Your columns will already have names. They are supplied by the database.
I would guess that your issue is with this line. If this isn't it please describe what you're expecting to happen, vs what is actually happening so that we may assist you better.

```
CarRGrid.DataSource = DataSetRentals2.Tables["CarRental"];
```

Which should probably be

```
CarRGrid.DataSource = DataSetRentals2;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question asked. However it doesn't seem to have helped the problem I was having. expecting to happen, vs what is actually I'm wanting to be able to click on a table with a parent key (CustomerNo) and have the corresponding records held by the child table (CarRental) be displayed (and no others) in the second data grid view